# How to create a Pandas dataframe from a file with 3-level nested json objects in Python

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have a large nested json file (one json-object per-line) that looks like below:

```
[{u'attributes': {u'By Appointment Only': True},
  u'business_id': u'vcNAWiLM4dR7D2nwwJ7nCA',
  u'categories': [u'Doctors', u'Health & Medical'],
  u'city': u'Phoenix',
  u'full_address': u'4840 E Indian School Rd\nSte 101\nPhoenix, AZ 85018',
  u'hours': {u'Friday': {u'close': u'17:00', u'open': u'08:00'},
   u'Monday': {u'close': u'17:00', u'open': u'08:00'},
   u'Thursday': {u'close': u'17:00', u'open': u'08:00'},
   u'Tuesday': {u'close': u'17:00', u'open': u'08:00'},
   u'Wednesday': {u'close': u'17:00', u'open': u'08:00'}},
  u'latitude': 33.499313,
  u'longitude': -111.983758,
  u'name': u'Eric Goldberg, MD',
  u'neighborhoods': [],
  u'open': True,
  u'review_count': 7,
  u'stars': 3.5,
  u'state': u'AZ',
  u'type': u'business'},
 {u'attributes': {u'Accepts Credit Cards': True,
   u'Alcohol': u'none',
   u'Ambience': {u'casual': False,
    u'classy': False,
    u'divey': False,
    u'hipster': False,
    u'intimate': False,
    u'romantic': False,
    u'touristy': False,
    u'trendy': False,
    u'upscale': False},
   u'Attire': u'casual',
   u'Caters': False,
   u'Delivery': False,
   u'Good For': {u'breakfast': False,
    u'brunch': False,
    u'dessert': False,
    u'dinner': False,
    u'latenight': False,
    u'lunch': True},
   u'Good For Groups': True,
   u'Good for Kids': True,
   u'Has TV': True,
   u'Noise Level': u'average',
   u'Outdoor Seating': False,
   u'Parking': {u'garage': False,
    u'lot': True,
    u'street': False,
    u'valet': False,
    u'validated': False},
   u'Price Range': 1,
   u'Take-out': True,
   u'Takes Reservations': False,
   u'Waiter Service': True},
  u'business_id': u'JwUE5GmEO-sH1FuwJgKBlQ',
  u'categories': [u'Restaurants'],
  u'city': u'De Forest',
  u'full_address': u'6162 US Highway 51\nDe Forest, WI 53532',
  u'hours': {},
  u'latitude': 43.238893,
  u'longitude': -89.335844,
  u'name': u'Pine Cone Restaurant',
  u'neighborhoods': [],
  u'open': True,
  u'review_count': 26,
  u'stars': 4.0,
  u'state': u'WI',
  u'type': u'business'}.... ]
```

The total length of the file is 42 153. The number of keys on the highest level is 15, and they are:
data[0].keys()

```
#[u'city',
# u'review_count',
# u'name',
# u'neighborhoods',
# u'type',
# u'business_id',
# u'full_address',
# u'hours',
# u'state',
# u'longitude',
# u'stars',
# u'latitude',
# u'attributes',
# u'open',
# u'categories']
```

I would like to iterate through the nested file and turn into into a dataframe in Python.
So far, I've create a dataframe like below, which was straightforward, but excluded two keys 'hours' and 'attributes' because they were nested.

```
keys = ['business_id', 'name', 'categories','type', 'city', 'state', 'full_address', 'latitude', 'longitude', 'neighborhoods', 'open', 'stars', 'review_count']
db = DataFrame(data, columns = keys)

In [371]: db[:3] 
Out[371]: 
              business_id                        name  \
0  vcNAWiLM4dR7D2nwwJ7nCA           Eric Goldberg, MD   
1  JwUE5GmEO-sH1FuwJgKBlQ        Pine Cone Restaurant   
2  uGykseHzyS5xAMWoN6YUqA  Deforest Family Restaurant   

                              categories      type       city state  \
0            [Doctors, Health & Medical]  business    Phoenix    AZ   
1                          [Restaurants]  business  De Forest    WI   
2  [American (Traditional), Restaurants]  business  De Forest    WI   

                                        full_address   latitude   longitude  \
0  4840 E Indian School Rd\nSte 101\nPhoenix, AZ ...  33.499313 -111.983758   
1            6162 US Highway 51\nDe Forest, WI 53532  43.238893  -89.335844   
2                505 W North St\nDe Forest, WI 53532  43.252267  -89.353437   

  neighborhoods  open  stars  review_count  
0            []  True    3.5             7  
1            []  True    4.0            26  
2            []  True    4.0            16
```

Could someone please suggest a way how I can create a similar dataframe for the nested keys 'hours' and
'attributes' in Python? I'm not sure what's the best way to iterate through the entire file to access nested keys and then turn them into the Dataframe. I've read a few answers to similar questions but couldn't quite find the answer that works for my case. For example, I would like the dataframe for 'attributes' to look something like:

```
Accepts Credit cards  Alcohol  Casual  Classy .... 
True                  None     False   True 
True                  None     True    True  
False                 None     False   False
```

thanks in advance for all your help!